# Number of player objects more than 30

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say I have an Array List of players and I want to get the all the players who are above the age of 30. The players have usual attributes like name and age and getName and getAge methods. I'm new to Java so any help here is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

for(player p: players){ if(p.getAge() > 30){ System.out.println(p.getName()); }}

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please at least show us a good faith attempt. This will A) give us a much better understanding of what you're trying to do and prevent all this trouble extracting exact information from you, and B) give us a much better understanding of what you might be doing wrong, what you need help with.

Comment: I'm trying to learn Java, practising a few exercises. I do know we have to iterate it through a for loop which is something like this: for(int i=0; i<players.size(); i++)

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30825239/edit), show us the Player class, show us your attempt to iterate through your `ArrayList<Player>`, etc...

Comment: Note that inside of the loop, you'll call the `getAge()` method on the current Player item, and do some checks on the value returned... Come on,... you can do this.... I have faith.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. Well, I'm trying actually, all I can think of is 
for(int i=0; i<players.size();i++){
Player player = player.getAge(), player.getName();
Something like this? I know i would have to use an IF statement too.

Comment: I could think of this as well:
for(player p: players){
if(p.getAge() > 30){
System.out.println(p.getName());
}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possible solution for you.
Assumption: you have a class Player and can read all players and add it in the allPlayers arraylist.

```
import java.util.*;

public class game
{
    //holds a list of all players.
    ArrayList<Player> allPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
    //holds a list of players older than 30 years.
    ArrayList<Player> olderThan30 = new ArrayList<Player>();

    public game()
    {
        //read players list and fill in the above arraylist with all players you have.
        //for example, allPlayers = getAllPlayers(); You can also use IO methods to read external files.
        //get all players that is older than 30 years of age by calling a method get30OlderPlayers().
        olderThan30 = get30OlderPlayers();
    }

    private ArrayList<Player> get30OlderPlayers()
    {
        //an arraylist that will save the player list to return.
        ArrayList<Player> olderThan30 = new ArrayList<Player>();

        //loops through all players one by one.
        for (Player p : allPlayers)
        {
            //if the player's age is more than 30....
            if(p.getAge() > 30)
            {
                //...add it to the arraylist olderThan30.
                olderThan30.add(p);
            }
        }
        //at the end return the arraylist that holds the players older than 30.
        return olderThan30;
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: This clears my doubt. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can do:

```
public List<Player> getAllOlderThan(int age) {
    return players.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > age).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```